# Windows phone 8.1 update 2

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, updates, lumia

I do not have the windows insider and yesterday when I checked for an update on my Lumia 535, an update named 'An important Lumia update for Windows phone' was available. I want to know if its GDR2 or is it the Windows phone 10 Technical Preview. And if I do get the Windows phone 10 Technical preview, will I be able to revert back to my old Lumia update?

Comment: ask this on here: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to [using a Windows Phone](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com), and not developing software for them.

Answer (score 0):

when you are about to download the update, it will tell you exactly what version is. And after the download is complete it will ask you once again if you want to install [versio number] on your phone

Comment: Nope. I was presented with no such information. It just said 'An important Lumia update for Windows phone'. Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

There is still no grd2 announced for the Lumia 535. If you are an insider you can download a Windows 10 tp. And yes, there is a way to revert back to Windows 8.1. Just use the Windows device recovery tool.